# How to join two large table in postgres and get data faster

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, large-data

I am working with two tables which contains huge data , over 10 million each.I have a requirement to join two tables to get the desired results, but due to high volume it is taking excessive time. I have tried to execute each operation of the both tables separately but i think my implementation is not correct .I am posting the table structure and the Query  i tried

```
CREATE TABLE supply.supply_detail (
  supply_detail_id bigint NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT nextval('supply.supply_detail_supply_detail_id_seq'::regclass),
  supl_num numeric(15,0),
  str numeric(7,0),
  supl_dte character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  supl_num character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  cl_lvl numeric(7,0),
  stp character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  poc_num numeric(3,0),
  qty numeric(6,0),
  sCost numeric(11,4)
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE supply.supply_header (
  supply_header_id bigint NOT NULL
    DEFAULT nextval('supply.supply_header_supply_header_id_seq'::regclass),
  supl_num numeric(15,0),
  supl_name character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  lclV character varying(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  mkt numeric(7,0),
  supl_dte character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  supl_num character varying(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  ctrl_num numeric(7,0),
  depar_dte character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  rrturn_typ character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  copy_on numeric(11,2),
  expense numeric(11,2),
  amt numeric(11,2),
  inv_dte character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  fndg_dte character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

This is the Query I have tried:

```
select SUPL_NUM, VND_NUM, SUPL_NAME, STORE
from (
  select
    supH.supl_num SUPL_NUM, supH.ora_vendor VND_NUM,
    supH.supl_name SUPL_NAME, supH.str STORE,
    supH.supl_dte, supH.supl_num Hsupl_NUM, supH.ctrl_num
  from supply.supply_header supH
 ) HTBL,
 (
   select
     supD.upc, supD.line_num,supD.qty_purchase,
     supD.cost,supD.retail, supD.adj_ind, supD.supl_num Dsupl_NUM
   from supply.supply_detail supD
 ) DTBL
 where Hsupl_NUM = Dsupl_NUM  
 AND Dsupl_NUM = '394140308130'
 AND SUPL_NUM = 41219
```

Can anyone suggest a better way of  writing this query which can give an optimum result in a minimum time.

Comment: Take a look at this [Slow queries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) for tips on how to improve performance and report the information necessary to help with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think one large factor in the performance question is that you didn't share whether you have any indexes created for either table - I think if you add an index on `supl_num` for both tables, you would get tremendously faster performance.

However, your best bet is to first look at `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your_query>` and see where the bottlenecks are.  If you post the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, we can try to help you better.

Note also that your `SUPL_NUM` is the same column as `supH.supl_num`, and if we simplify your query, it would look like this:

```
select supH.supl_num, supH.ora_vendor, supH.supl_name, supH.str
  from supply.supply_header supH
  join supply.supply_detail supD
    on supH.supl_num=supD.supl_num
 AND supD.supl_num='394140308130'
 AND supH.supl_num=41219;
```

This would return zero rows.